# Hull algorithm that excludes a given set of points?

Tags: geometry, algorithms, convex-hulls

Given a set of points A that have to be inside the hull, and a set of points B that have to be outside. It is clear that set A can be enclosed with a convex hull algorithm, but how can set B be excluded?

I am looking for a polygon that encloses A \ B on a 3D surface triangle mesh.

Edit:

Thanks @Magma for helping me clarify the problem with an additional property: The hull should have maximal area while having only vertices in A.

[image: Illustration of the problem]

Comment: Can you define precisely which properties the hull you are trying to construct should satisfy?

Comment: This does not make sense. Should the hull be convex? Otherwise the set $A\setminus B$ fulfills those criteria.

Comment: @magma I am a software engineer and not a mathematician myself, so I am struggling a bit with defining the problem in a mathematical way. I edited the post to include that I am looking for a polygon that includes A\B on a 3D surface triangle mesh. Does this make it more clear?

Comment: @daw Yes, I am looking for A \ B. I am looking for an algorithm similar to convex hull that computes the polygon that contains A\B.

Comment: I can think of several possible different definitions for your hull, each producing different results in general. Some examples: a) the hull should have maximal area while having only vertices in A, b) the hull should have minimal perimeter while being simply connected, c) the hull should have minimal perimeter while having all elements of  A as vertices.

Comment: @magma I see, thank you very much. In that case: The hull should have minimal area while having only vertices in A.

Comment: You want minimal area? That'll just be the minimum spanning tree of A.

Comment: @Magma Many thanks for the idea, I looked it up. It looks like minimum spanning tree is not a closed polygon, right? I am looking for a closed polygon. Or it is, but I need a polygon with no overlapping edges.

Comment: Yes, a closed polygon with minimal area would just be a slight widening of some spanning tree.

Comment: @Magma Ah I see, thank you. This is not what I had in mind, so I think I was wrong to say minimal area. I would to revise my statement to "the hull should have maximal area while having only vertices in A".

Comment: Also, excluded should be replaced to mean "excluded or on the edge" to be meaningful.  And are you looking for hulls in 2 dimensions or 3 dimensions?

Comment: @DanielV Many thanks for your comment. I see how "allowing" right turns at excluded points might work when using "excluded or on the edge". However, in my case the forbidden nodes must specifically be excluded. I guess the problem could be solved with "excluded or on the edge" and then I could apply an offset to all the forbidden nodes?